# Sequence Big O notation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_n$ a monotonically decreasing sequence $\in \mathbb{R}$, such that series $\sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent.  $$\exists s > 1: a_n = O (n^{-s}) $$ with $(n \rightarrow \infty)$  $$a_n = o(n^{-s})$$ with $(n \rightarrow \infty)$

I am searching for a counterexample where the statement is not true and a prove for the correct statement. 
(Note: $o,O$ means the Big-$O$ / Landau notation)

Comment: Take, for example, $a_n=1/(n\log^2n)$.